# Magento 1.9.3.2 Upgrade to latest version not working

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I have a Magento 1.9.3.2 website. I'm trying to upgrade it to the latest Magento 1.9 version which I think is 1.9.3.9. I went to the official website, and found this URL for downloading. https://magento.com/tech-resources/download I think they have changed it so we can not download the whole package as zip or tar file as we can earlier. Instead we need to download a **downloader.php** file now.

I donwloaded the downloader.php and upload it to my Magento root directory. I visited the downloader.php and followed the instruction.

[image]

This screenshot is the last step I seen. and When I click on **continue**, it will redirect me to my website. When I check the Magento version in admin panel, I can't see my Magento is upgraded, it still stay at 1.9.3.2.

Comment: They can still be downloaded as a zip file. under "Release archive" tab and scroll to almost bottom of the page.

Comment: You are right, I found the download zip file at the bottom of the page. I didn't see this in the begining, that's why I thought It's only the downloader.php that is supported now. Thanks for the help